# ValueError: shape mismatch:

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, binary

I'm trying to create upper triangle matrices using binary sets:

I'm creating all possible n x n binary matrices with just upper triangle values (excluding the diagonal).  I am able to do a for loop for the n = 3 case.   That is 3 x 3 matrix with 2^3 = 8 permuations.  So 8 matrices.  When I do n = 4, 5, 6, ... I get a shape mismatch error.  Not sure why the for loop won't iterate.

See code example below:

```
n = 3
# Now we need to make permutation of binary upper_count tuples
# This will give 2^n sets of n binary values.  
from itertools import *
t1 = list(product([0,1],repeat= n)) 
print(t1)
print('\n')

# Now we create 2^n matrices of size nxn:
for i in t1:
  m1 = np.zeros((n,n))

  indices = np.triu_indices_from(m1,1) 
  upper = m1[indices]

  m1[indices] = i
  print(m1)
  print('\n')
```

**Gives the following desired output:**

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]


[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]


[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]


[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]


[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]


[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]


[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]


[[0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]


[[0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

**For n = 4:**

*I get the following error.*  **What am I missing?**

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]


---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-68-75f42bce2989> in <cell line: 8>()
     12   upper = m1[indices]
     13 
---> 14   m1[indices] = i
     15   print(m1)
     16   print('\n')

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (6,)
```

Comment: did you look at `indices`?

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't it match?  Or how do I get it to fit?

Comment: Well don't leave us in suspense!  What are they?  What does `m1[indices]` produce?  How does that compare to `i`, a row of `t1`?

Comment: Do I have to be explicit?  The upper tri of a (4,4) array has 6 nonzero terms (count them yourself).  But your `product` with n=4 produces 4 element tuples.  Most of the time 4 does not equal 6!

Comment: Yup...I didn't count t1 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My t1 was wrong.  I didn't count the set correct.

```
from itertools import *
size_n = (n*(n-1))/2 
size_n = int(size_n)
t1 = list(product([0,1],repeat= size_n))
```

Updated code:

```
n = 4
# Now we need to make permutation of binary upper_count tuples
from itertools import *
size_n = (n*(n-1))/2 
size_n = int(size_n)
t1 = list(product([0,1],repeat= size_n))
print(t1)
print('\n')

for i in t1:
  print(i)
  m1 = np.zeros((n,n))

  indices = np.triu_indices_from(m1,1)
  print('\n') 
  # print(m1)
  upper = m1[indices] # error here.  
  # print(upper)

  m1[indices] = i
  print(m1)
  print('\n')
```

**Desired Results**

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]


(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)


[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)


[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)


[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)


[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)


[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)


[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)


[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)


[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)


[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)


[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)


[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)


[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)


[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)


[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)


[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)


[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)


[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)


[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)


[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)


[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)


[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)


[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)


[[0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)


[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)


[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)


[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)


[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)


[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)


[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)


[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)


[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)


[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)


[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)


[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)


[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)


[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)


[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)


[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)


[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)


[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)


[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)


[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)


[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)


[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)


[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)


[[0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)


[[0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)


[[0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)


[[0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)


[[0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)


[[0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)


[[0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)


[[0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)


[[0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)


[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)


[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)


[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)


[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)


[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)


[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)


[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]


(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)


[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```